# Do content types play any role for ecommerce product webpages?

Tags: commerce, 10

Content types (Node types) have always been a great way to organize Drupal content, especially when combining blocks in nodes of certain content types and/or certain node IDs or preventing them from appearing in these programatically.

We consider to build an ecommerce website with Drupal, something we never did.

Do content types play any role for ecommerce product webpages?
For example, should content types be utilized to organize types of "product nodes" or should the traditional Drupal ecommerce modules provide a whole different secondary mechanism to organize product webpages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Drupal 8, Commerce Core defines a new type of content entity named Product to serve the function of product display page as opposed to Node, which we used in Drupal 7 and earlier. Modules that used to only work with Node generally work with any type of content entity, and we have rarely encountered a scenario where the default Product entity type is insufficient. (e.g., I think comments may not work on every type of content entity yet - can't recall, been a while since I tried.)